# Is there anything in the literature that supports revolutionary claims for this "new" sulfuric-acid battery?

Tags: electrochemistry

I've got the following from a [supposed new energy-storage technologist](http://megglobal.com/commitment.html). It's supposed to be a fancy new cheap, high-powered, highly scalable battery. I want to know if this is known chemistry, and if there's anything genuinely revolutionary about it:

> "Basic materials in MEG's E-SOURCE™ power cells are lead metal, absorptive glass mat paper, and sulfuric acid solution. Materials unique to the MEG advanced power cell are S2 glass fiber yarn; sodium sulfate; Teflon emulsion, glass-filled polypropylene; bituminous, petroleum-based wax; and metal-free nano-oxides. "

The lead is apparently in the form of lead oxide.

The claim is that this is a radical new cheap energy-storage system - but someone makes that claim for yet another technology every week or two. Is there anything in the recent literature that would give credibility to this one?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing in the chemistry of what they describe that is different in any way to a conventional Lead-Acid battery. What they really seem to claim is improvement in materials in the battery not to change the electrochemistry but to improve other aspects of battery operation. [For example](http://megglobal.com/about.html):

> MEG's E-SOURCE™ power cell technology is based on a lead-fiberglass composite material that is one-third the weight and 50 times the strength of metal alloys used in conventional batteries. To date, more than $100 million has been invested in research, development, manufacturing, and market testing of this technology in the United States and several international markets.

This suggests they have built a better lead-acid battery rather than something more radical. This is not ridiculous. They claim the following advantages:

> - Extraordinary manufacturing and user cost savings
> - Significant weight reduction compared to conventional lead-acid    batteries
> - Exceptionally long service life
> - Dramatically fast recharge speeds at all operating temperatures
> - Safe, simple, and low-cost maintenance

It is not impossible to imagine clever overall design and improved microstructural components and electrode materials could deliver these sorts of improvements and it is certainly far easier than inventing a whole new battery electrochemistry. For example, charging speed is often dominated by the physical material properties of the electrodes and not the underlying electrode chemistry, so clever design can mitigate the physical limits on charging speed such as by increasing the effective surface area.

Comment: Sodium sulfate isn't in a normal lead-acid battery, is it?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers True, but there is plenty of sulphate as this is essential to the reactions. So sodium sulphate won't change the electrochemistry.